# Sort items in list alphabetically

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I am trying to sort this list alphabetically, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```kotlin
items = dataList.groupBy { it.category }
    .map {
        listOf(
            Header(
                "res.Strings.customName${it.key.name}" ?: it.key.name
            )
        ).also {
            it.sortedBy { it.title }
        }
    }
```

items is a `List<Any>`

My dataList is a list of object;

```
data class Object(
val category: Enum,
val list: List<AnotherObject>
)
```

I try to display a list divided to categories:

```
Category1
 Item1
 ...
Category2
 Item1
 ...
```

etc.

I want to sort Categories alphabetically.

Comment: What's the type of `dataList`?

Comment: List<MyCustomObject>

Comment: ...and your custom object has `category` and `title` properties I guess? And the type of `category` has a `name` property? It would help to show the class definitions for a reproducible example. There are multiple things that are done wrong here, so having a complete picture would help us help you.

Comment: Which of those lists are you trying to sort alphabetically? The list of items in `dataList`? The list of categories? The list of `Header`s built from the categories?

Comment: I have some Headers. Every single contains a list with items. I want to sort Header list.

I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: given your edited question, it seems like you're looking for something much simpler (no `Header` object here):

```kotlin
val items = dataList.sortedBy { it.category.name }
```

This will give you an ordered list of your so called `Object` class. If you want to also convert these elements to `Header` instances, you can use `map` afterwards, but remember that you'll need to keep the list of elements as well in your objects (which you are not doing in your original code)

---

##### Original answer

There are multiple incorrect things here:

1. `sortedBy` is used on a list of one single `Header` element, so it basically does nothing
2. `sortedBy` returns a new sorted list, so even if applied to the correct list, you're not using its result because you use `also` (which doesn't return the result of the lambda)
3. you're not using the values of your initial list in any way, just their categories, so you might as well forget `groupBy` and just extract the categories

```kotlin
items = dataList.groupBy { it.category }
    .map { // here it.key is a category and it.value (the list of items) is never used
        listOf( // creates a list of a single element of type Header
            Header(
                // this elvis operator is never used because the string is never null
                "res.Strings.customName${it.key.name}" ?: it.key.name
            )
        ).also { // will return the "unsorted" list of one Header element
            // returns the "sorted" 1-element list (so the same list) 
            // but the result is ignored anyway by also{}
            it.sortedBy { it.title }
        }
    }
```

It's a bit difficult to get what you're trying to achieve, but assuming you want to extract categories and build a sorted `Header`s list out of it, here is what you could do:

```kotlin
items = dataList.map { Header("res.Strings.customName${it.category.name}") }
                .sortedBy { it.title }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sortedBy` does not sort in-place, it returns a new List: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html

`also` returns the original object (`it`), not the return value of the lambda, if you use let (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#let) it should work as that will return the result of `it.sortedBy`.

Alternatively you could keep `also`, map to a `MutableMap` and sort in-place, but that would probably be needless complication here.

Comment: I've changed also to let and it still not working

Comment: On closer look your datatypes aren't making much sense. You go from List<MyCustomObject> to Map<String(?), MyCustomObject> to List<List<Header>>, you then sort that inner list, but probably want to sort the outer list. Try removing the listOf(), which is creating that 1-element inner list. And then move the sort outside the map.

Comment: to List<List<Header>> I add (.plus)  another mapped list from  List<MyCustomObject>.
MyCustomObject contains list with items that I map and add to List<Header>

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list alpabetically like below

```
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
list.add("c")
list.add("b")
list.add("a")
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy { it })
print(sortedList)

output:[a,b,c]

For your problem replace compareBy{it} with compareBy{it.category}
```